# In a git hook is the current working directory guaranteed to be within the git repository?

Tags: git

Experimentally it seems that git hooks get run with the current directory set to be the root of the repository. However, I can't see any guarantee about that in the git documentation. Should I rely on the current working directory to locate the git repository, or is there a better way to work out the git repository associated with the hook?

Comment: Not sure how much that is related. On a Gentoo stable box with Git 2.7.3(-r1) git hooks are not only executed in `.git` but `git reset --hard` actually creates the working directory structure inside the `.git` directory which, in my opinion is an entirely wrong thing to do!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is based on the value set for environment variable `GIT_DIR`. It is set to the root of the repository when the hook starts running. Many hooks, especially those doing a pull from another repo, unset ( and reset) this environment variable as needed.

Comment: Does $GIT_DIR has a trailing slash ?

Comment: This is NOT a correct answer. GIT_DIR is NOT always set to the root of the repo. See [this blog](http://longair.net/blog/2011/04/09/missing-git-hooks-documentation/).

Comment: @Ghopper21 That article isn't entirely correct either. It says that for the post-commit hook, the current directory is the top level of the working tree. However, my very simple post-commit script didn't find other scripts at the top level of the working tree. e.g.: `.git/hooks/post-commit: 1: .git/hooks/post-commit: post-commit_push_gitweb.sh: not found`

Answer (score 116):

The current answers appear to be outdated. As of 2.9.0, the docs state the following:

> Before Git invokes a hook, it changes its working directory to either
>   the root of the working tree in a non-bare repository, or to the
>   $GIT_DIR in a bare repository.

https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks/2.9.0

Comment: Great answer. A clarification was made in later revisions (2.13.0). **"An exception are hooks triggered during a push (pre-receive, update, post-receive, post-update, push-to-checkout) which are always executed in $GIT_DIR."**

Comment: Source/context for the above quote: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_description

Comment: In plain language: it's the top-level directory of your repository. ("Bare" essentially refers to a repository consisting of only the `.git` directory, and with no files checked out.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the environment variable `$GIT_DIR`. `$GIT_DIR` points at the `.git` directory.

Comment: How likely is it that `$GIT_DIR/..` will point to the repository root?

Comment: It's not foolproof. Don't use ``$GIT_DIR/..``. That will break when the repo is a bare repo. A bare repo has no working directory hence no "repository root". Also it will break when .git is a link instead.

Comment: Figured. Any way to get the repo root under normal usage? For a pre-commit hook which uses the repo as configuration files for a program, for instance?

Comment: This is NOT correct in all cases. See [this blog](http://longair.net/blog/2011/04/09/missing-git-hooks-documentation/).