# gitolite post receive hook for specific bare repo

Tags: git, gitolite

After I push my local git repo to the server:

```
$ git push origin master
```

I want the bare repo on the server (after it received the push from me) to:

```
$ cd /Users/me/Sites
$ git pull
$ exit
```

I've looked at some questions here and they mention hooks in $HOME/gitolite/hooks,

but here's what I'm working with:

```
git@mm:gitolite $ pwd
/Users/git/gitolite
git@mm:gitolite $ ls
.git/                 README.txt            install*
CHANGELOG             check-g2-compat*      src/
COPYING               convert-gitosis-conf* t/
```

How do I add a post-receive hook for a specific bare repo?

If I go into my bare repo:

```
git@mm:bare-repo.git $ ls hooks
applypatch-msg.sample*     pre-rebase.sample*
commit-msg.sample*         prepare-commit-msg.sample*
post-update.sample*        update@
pre-applypatch.sample*     update.sample*
pre-commit.sample*
```

I don't see a post-receive hook. What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update August 2013, with the latest gitolite:
You now have [official specific repo hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18431200/6309):

> it's basically just creating a symlink in `<repo.git>/hooks` pointing to some file inside `$rc{LOCAL_CODE}/hooks/repo-specific` (except the `gitolite-admin` repo)

---

Original answer (

First, if you are using gitolite V3, you can define any hook, including a `post-receive` hook (except the `update` hook, see [**using hooks**](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#hooks)) : previously, with [gitolite V2](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#hooks), `pre-receive` hook was reserved.

Now you can add a hook by copying it in the `gitolite-admin/common/hooks` local clone directory, and pushing `gitolite-admin` back to the gitolite server: gitolite will make sure that hook is declared for *all* bare repos it manages.

You can also add directly your hook on the server at a separate location designed by the `$LOCAL_CODE` "`rc`" variable ("`rc`" means defined in your [`gitolite.rc` config file](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rc.html)): `$LOCAL_CODE/hooks/common`. See "[customizing gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#localcode)".
The idea is to make sure a gitolite upgrade doesn't erase any of your custom programs.

Simply define a 'post-receive' file, executable (`chmod 755`), and copy it in the `common/hooks` directory of your choice (`gitolite-admin` local repo plus `git push`, or `.gitolite` on the server, or `$LOCAL_CODE` on the server).
Note: that fact that you don't see a '`post-receive.sample`' file doesn't prevent you to define that hook.
If done directly on the server, you need then to run `gitolite setup --hooks-only` in order for your custom hooks to be setup on *all* bare repos.

What you would never do is to copy it directly on one of your `bare-repo.git/hooks` directory: that is the job of gitolite to publish "common" hooks to all your bare repo.
That way, you can manage them directly through any clone of `gitolite-admin` repo (pushing back that repo will update any hook that you might have changed).

"All bare repo" means your `post-receive` hook must know what bare repo it operates on:
You can do that by [checking the value of `$GIT_DIR`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065224/in-a-git-hook-is-the-current-working-directory-guaranteed-to-be-within-the-git-r) (set to the root `.git` directory of the bare repo on which this hook is running).

Finally, for this kind of `post-receive` hook, see "[Git checkout in `post-receive` hook: “`Not a git repository '.'`”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507942/git-checkout-in-post-receive-hook-not-a-git-repository)":
You need to define `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` explicitly to the *destination* repo in order for your `git pull` to succeed.

```
 GIT_WORK_TREE=/Users/me/Sites GIT_DIR=/Users/me/Sites/.git git pull
```

Comment: I tried to setup repo-specific-hooks(v3) using the following:

**1** I created `LOCAL_CODE =>  "$ENV{HOME}/.gitolite/local",` in rc
**2** I add `'repo-specific-hooks',` to ENABLE array in rc, 
**3** I created dir `local/hooks/repo-specific/` in my gitolite-admin, commited and pushed that
**4** I add string: `option hook.post-receive = deploy` in conf/gitolite.conf for `testing` repo, created file `local/hooks/repo-specific/deploy` in conf file with 0755, and commited and pushed them... 
**5** I made commit/push to testing repo, hook was not fired, 

what I did wrong ?

Comment: symlink also not here, tried to run `gitolite setup --hooks-only` without any success

Comment: @eicto I have edited tha answer with a link to repo-specific hook in gitolite: make sure you have the latest gitolite though.

Comment: just not understand, how can I place \t in commandline here:

`gitolite git-config gitolite-options.hook=reponame hookname scriptname` 
I readed and rereaded docs many times, and still not understand why it just ignores all configs here.  Can you give any non abstract sample of configuration, when we have git controlled hook directory(in local), and simple repo-specific hook saying "Hello world" on post-receive ? **gitolite version 3.5.2**

Comment: @eicto 3.5.2 is too old to contains repo-specific hook. You need to clone https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite and update your current gitolite installation.

Comment: @eicto the installation or update is very easy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18503812/6309

Answer (score 0):

To get a repo-specific post-commit hook (gitolite v3.6 and above):

1. Edit gitolite.rc, **comment in** the line 'repo-specific-hooks' (which should be commented out by default).
2. Run `gitolite setup`.  It will complain about a directory path that's missing.  Go and create it. `mkdir -p /git/local/hooks/repo-specific`.
3. Add your post-receive hook to that dir:

   `cd /git/local/hooks/repo-specific`

   `echo "stuff to do" > post-receive`

   `chmod o+x post-receive`
4. Add the post-receive hook to the desired repo(s) in `gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf`:

   `repo fooBar`

   `option hook.post-receive = post-receive`
5. Re-run `gitolite setup`.  There shouldn't be any error messages.
6. Commit something to `foorBar` and watch the magic happen.

If you want to debug why it's not working, have a look in `~/.gitolite/logs`.  Also check that your version is above 3.6.

If you want a post-receive action to happen to **any** repo that is under gitolite control, and you don't care which one, then simply add your `post-receive` script to `~/.gitolite/hooks/common`.