# Why can't I run vagrant ssh in a pre-commit hook?

Tags: vagrant, phpunit, pre-commit-hook

I've got a very basic `pre-commit`-hook with the following code in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
vagrant ssh -c "/var/www/public/tests.sh"
```

But whenever I try to commit I get the following message:

```
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 2: vagrant: command not found
```

Vagrant is installed and it is running. If I execute the command manually it works, only if Git tries to run it, it doesn't.

I already tried the following:

- Add an extra script `pre-commit.sh` in the root of my project and calling that from the pre-commit hook.
- Added absolute path to Vagrant binary in my pre-commit hook, but then I get the message my virtual box is not running (although it is).

Answer (score 1):

The pre-commit is running in its own shell with its own environment. It does not necessarily share your environment, aka your *PATH* or current directory. You need to be explicit in your pre-commit hook. So yes, you either need to specify the full path to the *vagrant* binary or you have to make sure that *PATH* is properly setup for the environment which runs the pre-commit hook.

The reason you get the "virtual box is not running" message when using the full path is, that the commit hook is not executed in the same directory as your *Vagrantfile*. Is your *Vagrantfile* in the root of the git repository. Then I would expect it to work - see [In a git hook is the current working directory guaranteed to be within the git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065224/in-a-git-hook-is-the-current-working-directory-guaranteed-to-be-within-the-git-r)

If your *Vagrantfile* is located somehwere else, you have a few options.
You can set *VAGRANT_CWD* and give Vagrant a hint where your *Vagrantfile* is located (see https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/) or you specify the id of the running box:

```
vagrant ssh <box-id> ...
```

One can use

```
vagrant global-status
```

to determine this id. Or you just make sure that the script changes into the directory of the *Vagrantfile*.