# Git Pre-Commit Hook: Unable to Run `dartfmt` (command not found) (Windows)

Tags: bash, git, flutter, dart

Ideally, I would like to have `dartfmt` to format my code on every commit, and I think that `git hooks` are ideal for this. So far, I've tried the code found in [this link](http://blog.sethladd.com/2015/04/formatting-dart-code-before-every-git.html), but with no success, despite it appearing on multiple other websites — maybe it's outdated.

In the end, I think nothing much more complicated than this should work in most cases (inside the `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

dartfmt -w . # or maybe `flutter format .` for Flutter
```

The errors I get are:

- For `dartfmt -w .`: `dartfmt: command not found`
- For `flutter format .`:  `find: ‘>     bin [’: No such file or directory`

Both of those commands do work if placed directly in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

to make `dartfmt` work, try running `which dartfmt` manually to get the path to the executable, and then use the absolute path when calling it in the script.

If `which` isn't able to find it, and assuming you know the complete path to the directory where `dartfmt` is located, try adding that directory to PATH in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/path/to/dart-sdk/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Also, I'd suggest taking a moment double check what `git` will use for the working directory when it calls those hook scripts. There might be some undesired behavior by using `.` if the CWD isn't what is expected. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065224/in-a-git-hook-is-the-current-working-directory-guaranteed-to-be-within-the-git-r).

Comment: Strangely, when I try `which dartfmt`, I get things like `/usr/bin/which: no dartfmt in (/c/Program Files/Python38/Script ,,,`, Maybe I need to add it to the `PATH`?

Comment: The bizarre thing is that, in `git`'s shell (Windows), even though the `dart-sdk` seems to be in the `PATH` (`env | grep PATH`), I still get `bash: dartfmt: command not found`. Maybe `dartfmt` cannot be run from `git`? I don't know what's going on here.

Comment: Definitely try adding the actual complete path for `dartfmt` to `PATH` and then `export` it too. Add `PATH="[/c/[....]/path/to/dart-sdk/bin]:$PATH"; export PATH;` and see what you get. If you can run it manually there is no reason it shouldn't work from the git hook. It is for sure a path problem. You could also try taking the output of `env | grep PATH` and copy/pasting it into the hook script, assigning it as `PATH` and `export` it.

Comment: Still not working even after doing putting in your suggestion, unfortunately. I tried it with `PATH="/c/src/flutter/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:$PATH"`.

Answer (score 0):

To format your dart code regularly, you can follow one of the two ways mentioned below:

**Preferred way**:

In IntelliJ Idea go to `Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Flutter -> Select Format Code on save option.`

This will format your code every few seconds. This is preferred because you can customize your personal formatting settings such as max words in a line etc.

[image]

**Alternatively**

From [Official website](https://dart.dev/tools/dartfmt) run `dartfmt -w bin lib` to format your code from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Add `dartfmt` reference in `PATH`, like this:

```sh
export PATH="/xxx/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:$PATH"
```