git hook is triggered but not executed
I created a post-receive hook like that
.git/hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh

set -x
touch file

and...
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-receive

when I push from the local repo I can see the debug message
remote: + touch file

but I don't see the file created in the remote repo
ls .git/hooks

but when I manually execute the hook (as a normal sh file) the file is generated
sh .git/hooks/post-receive

update:
solved by @eftshift0
the git doesn't execute the hook from .git/hooks, i.e. the current working dir is somewhere else.
using an absolute path confirmed this point of view
touch /home/file

and now I can see the file is created after each push

Is the hook executed in .git/hooks? Check in other directories.

yes it is executed because I see the debug messages in the local repo @eftshift0

If that is really your script, you should replace the !# with a proper hash-bang, #!.

sorry it just a typo in the question's description, but the hashbang is correct

My question is not if it is executed.... I assume, according to your description, that it does run..... what I am asking is where git is running the hook from. It sounds like you assume that it is run from within .git/hook (as in .git/hooks is the working directory)..... is that the case?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065224/in-a-git-hook-is-the-current-working-directory-guaranteed-to-be-within-the-git-r

aha I got your point, let's test again using absolute paths @eftshift0

you are right, using absolute paths solved the issue, now I can see the file is created. thank you so much @eftshift0

please post an answer to vote up for it @eftshift0

I don't think so.... it's a duplicate of the question I pointed to. Let me mark it as such.

as you can see, but you really saved my life
